# get OpenFileDialog button pressed

Tags: visual-c++, msdn, openfiledialog

I'm using an OpenFileDialog to let the user chose a file to open.
it works, but if I chose a file and insted of pressing OK I press CANCEL it still opens the file because I picked up one.

I found this code in the MSDN, but I can't see ::DialogResult::OK in my apllication

```
if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == ::DialogResult::OK )
  {
     if ( (myStream = openFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr )
     {
        // Insert code to read the stream here.
        myStream->Close();
     }
  }
```

my code is:

```
fileD1->ShowDialog();
while(!fileD->FileName->Lenght!=0)
{
}
and here I open the file
```

any other idea of how to know which button I pressed?
I'm using c++ and visual studio 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save the return of this ->> openFileDialog1->ShowDialog()

into a value and then check the value

DialogResult::OK

or

DialogResult::CANCEL